# Why is this array of chars changing value when another function is called?

Tags: c++, string

Why does my comportstr get changed in this code to a garbage value? I don't understand how my char array could change values if nothing about it is altered. There is nothing else between those two print statements.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{  
    char comportstr[10];
    sprintf(comportstr,"COM%d",COMPORT_NUM);
    if(DEBUGGING) fprintf(stderr,"str is: %s\n", comportstr); //prints str is: COM3
    sprintf(curtime , "%s" , currentDateTime());
    if(DEBUGGING) fprintf(stderr,"str is: %s\n", comportstr); //prints str is: ;32
}
```

Here's what currentDateTime does. It doesn't modify comportstr at all.

```
// Gets current date/time, format is YYYY-MM-DD.HH;mm;ss
const std::string currentDateTime() 
{
    time_t     now = time(0);
    struct tm  tstruct;
    char       buf[80];
    tstruct = *localtime(&now);
    // Visit http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/strftime/
    // for more information about date/time format
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d.%H;%M;%S", &tstruct);

    return buf;
}
```

Comment: char curtime[16]; Sorry I left that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `currentDateTime()` function you are returning a `std::string` which is passed to `sprintf()`'s vararg interface. That doesn't work as you can't pass standard layout types to vararg interfaces. That is, the second call to `sprintf()` results in undefined behavior.

You can avoid the problem by using

```
sprintf(curtime , "%s" , currentDateTime().c_str());
```

... or, actually,

```
strcpy(curtime, currentDateTime().c_str());
```

Comment: Thanks, though that was not my main issue. I still have the problem where I get a garbage value in comportstr for some reason. I replaced the sprintf with strcpy but nothing changed.

Comment: What's the size of your `curtime` array?

Comment: I declared it as char curtime[16];

Comment: That would be too small! Use `snprintf()` and/or `strncpy()` (I should have suggested these in the first places) with the proper size, e.g., `snprintf(sizeof(curtime), currentDateTime().c_str())` or `strncpy(curtime, currentDateTime().c_str(), sizeof(curtime))` (I keep forgetting if that gets null terminated if the string is too long...).

Comment: Oh wait, my curtime array was too short for the output of currentDateTime. I increased it to 30 and I fixed the issue. I don't understand though, why would comportstr be affected?

Comment: @user2619824: Well, it is a buffer overrun. Another source of undefined behavior. Likely the two buffers a located next to each other and you got the 3 excess characters written to your `compportstr` array. You might have noticed that the garbage changed with the seconds passing...

Comment: @user2619824: What do _you_ think a buffer overrun does?

Comment: I'm new to C++ :x

Thanks Mr. Kühl

Answer (score 1):

```
sprintf(curtime , "%s" , currentDateTime());
```

The `currentDateTime` function returns a `std::string`, but `%s` is for C-style strings only. You want `currentDateTime().c_str()`. Your compiler should have given you a warning.